# Working with git stash with different branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two branches `feature/A` and `feature/B`. I have modified the files of `feature/A` and apply `git stash` command to save my work and `git checkout feature/B` to switch to other branch. Now on `feature/B` I have modified files and applies `git stash` to save the work at `feature/B`.

Now if I want to again reflect my changes I have to apply `git stash pop` but my question is the saved work of both the branches reflect at once when I apply `git stash pop` or the work is saved as per the branches (i.e. In `feature/A` the work of particular branch only reflects and in `feature/B` the work of particular branch is reflect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pop or apply the relevant stash by index upon returning to the `feature/A` branch.  Consider this workflow:

```
# work on feature/A
git stash

# work on feature/B
git checkout feature/B
git stash

# now return to feature/A and apply the first stash
git checkout feature/A
git stash apply "stash@{0}"

# switch to feature/B and apply the correct stash there
git checkout feature/B
git stash apply "stash@{1}"
```